# Scala compile error “value max is not a member of Int"

Tags: scala

In the following code:

```scala
case class Token(name: String, number: Int)
 

tokensDAO.getTokenSeq().map(

   tokenSeq => tokenSeq.map(_.number).fold(0)(_ max _)
       
)
```

What might possibly be the cause of this compile error?

> value max is not a member of Int

The error can be reproduced when the `tokenSeq` is retrieved from the JDBC database. It is the HikariCP connection pool on the Play Framework.

Since the problem got solved by `import Predef.intWrapper`, which shouldn't normally be needed, the full imports are included for further scrutiny:

```scala
import java.io.{ File, PrintWriter }
import models.{ DownloadToken, User }
import models.daos.{ DownloadDAO, UserDAO }
import Predef.intWrapper
import java.util.UUID

import scala.util.Random

import java.security.SecureRandom
import javax.inject.Inject
import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, Future }

import java.util.Base64
```

This is the signature of the class:

```
class DownloadServiceImpl @Inject() (downloadDAO: DownloadDAO, userDAO: UserDAO, configuration: play.api.Configuration)(implicit ex: ExecutionContext) extends DownloadService
```

This is the full `scalacOptions` on `build.sbt` as requested in the comments:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-deprecation", // Emit warning and location for usages of deprecated APIs.
  "-feature", // Emit warning and location for usages of features that should be imported explicitly.
  "-unchecked", // Enable additional warnings where generated code depends on assumptions.
  "-Xfatal-warnings", // Fail the compilation if there are any warnings.
  //"-Xlint", // Enable recommended additional warnings.
  "-Ywarn-dead-code", // Warn when dead code is identified.
  "-Ywarn-numeric-widen", // Warn when numerics are widened.
  // Play has a lot of issues with unused imports and unsued params
  // https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/6690
  // https://github.com/playframework/twirl/issues/105
  "-Xlint:-unused,_"
)
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is real? or maybe it is just an IDE error? Have you tried compiling the code using **sbt**, **maven**, or whatever build tool you are using?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yes. `sbt compile` gives me the same error on debian. I suspected it might have something to do with the `tokenSeq` being fetched from the database. Nevertheless, the type  of `tokenSeq` is `Seq[Token]`.

Comment: That is very weird then, [I can't reproduce the error](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/Dmigx9WtRKa8AKNx37TsnA/1) I tried with multiple **Scala** versions, including `2.10.6` which is the oldest **Scastie** let me use, maybe you are using an even older version? Like `2.9`?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. My Scala version is `2.13.1`. The problem got solved with the suggested import in the accepted answer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The error can almost exclusively be reproduced when the `tokenSeq` is retrieved from the database. It is the `HikariCP` connection pool on the `Play Framework`.

Comment: @user221678 Nothing in your question itself shows it is related to JDBC, and if it is you need to make that explicit and provide a [mre]. Based on the accepted answer I don't think this has anything to do with JDBC itself, and your use of a database (and JDBC) seems to be tangential to the actual problem.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks. I added more explanation on the context of the problem to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`max` is provided on `Int` via implicit extension method. Try

```
import Predef.intWrapper
tokensDAO.getTokenSeq().map(...)
```

If that works then, something might be interfering with default import of `scala.Predef`.

Comment: My supposition is that such **Int** is not really `scala.int`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez According to `number: Int` in `Token` seems it is.

Comment: @user221678 Maybe show us the imports so we can see the culprit. Note you shouldn't really need to explicitly `import Predef.intWrapper`

Comment: @MarioGalic I included them by editing the answer.

Comment: @user221678 Can you also show full `scalacOptions` from `build.sbt`?

Comment: @MarioGalic edited the answer and included it.

Comment: @user221678 Is there anything else called `intWrapper` in your codebase?

Comment: @MarioGalic No, yet strangely, as I was working with the code, I changed the same file and recompiled it multiple times. The last time I commented your suggested import and now it successfully compiles. It was a compiler error, most probably.

Comment: I also used to have a problem with using `println()` in the same context related to some `predef`  import